# Angularjs link issue in html5Mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-history

I am using `angularjs` , and I am using `html5Mode`.

Before using `html5Mode` , links work in both same page and **new tab**. Link like this:

`http://localhost:81/vahidnajafi/#/about`

But in html5Mode, it works only in same page, but when I open it in new tab it goes to `404 Not found` page.

`http://localhost:81/vahidnajafi/about`

Thanks.

Comment: What type of web server are you using?

Comment: `html5Mode` is for single page app so it expect the app to be a single page. It works as expected and described in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).

Comment: Essentially, make sure you reference your angular app's home directory in the express app: 

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app_client')));
app.use(function (req,res){
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, 'app_client', 'index.html'))
});

and make sure your templateUrl routing property begins with /, so it knows to reference the location of your templates from the root directory, not the current directory.

Comment: @awimley Thanks. Where should I use this code?

Comment: The templateUrl fixes, using / at the beginning of all of them, should be used where you use ngRoute or routeProvider. The rest (starts with app.use) should be in your express application.

Comment: @awimley Sorry, but again I couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your need to redirect or reroute the request to your root url on the server.

Your server returns a 404 before angular gets the chance to do something with that route.